# Exactly how does this class variable work?

Tags: java

I am quite confused about class variables. I am looking over the Java Doc tutorials. They explained static variables and methods, but I do not really understand one of the concepts. They gave us some code and asked us what the answers would come out.

**NOTE THE CODE IS NOT COMPLETELY CORRECT. IT IS NOT TO RUN THE PROGRAM BUT TO GRASP THE CONCEPT OF STATIC VARIABLES**

The code is this:

```
public class IdentifyMyParts {
    public static int x = 7;
    public int y = 3;
}
```

From the Following code above what is the output of code:

```
IdentifyMyParts a = new IdentifyMyParts();  //Creates an instance of a class
IdentifyMyParts b = new IdentifyMyParts();  //Creates an instance of a class

a.y = 5;    //Setting the new value of y to 5 on class instance a     
b.y = 6;    //Setting the new value of y to 6 on class instance b
a.x = 1;    //Setting the new value of static variable of x to 1 now.
b.x = 2;    //Setting the new value of static variable of x to 2 now.

System.out.println("a.y = " + a.y);  //Prints 5
System.out.println("b.y = " + b.y);  //Prints 6
System.out.println("a.x = " + a.x);  //Prints 1
System.out.println("b.x = " + b.x);  //Prints 2
System.out.println("IdentifyMyParts.x = " + IdentifyMyParts.x); 

//Prints2  <- This is because the static variable holds the new value of 2 
//which is used by the class and not by the instances.
```

Am I missing something because it says that System.out.println("a.x = " + a.x);  //Prints 1 actually prints 2.

Comment: Please stop typing in bold all-caps. **IT'S REALLY ANNOYING**.

Comment: Sorry. I noticed that people get annoyed when the code is not correctly shown. I wanted to make sure it wasn't about the code, but about the concept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Static variables are shared across all instances of the class. So `a.x` and `b.x` actually refer to the same thing: static variable `x`.

You're essentially doing the following:

```
IdentifyMyParts.x = 1;
IdentifyMyParts.x = 2;
```

So x ends up as 2.

*Edit:*
Based on the comment below, it seems the confusion may be due to `//Prints 1`. Anything after // is a comment, and has no effect at all on the code. In this case the comment is suggesting that the System.out of a.x will print 1, but it is incorrect (as comments that aren't maintained often are...)

Comment: I understand that. My question is about what it prints out. I got the one at the end of the code wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking then...a.x, b.x and IdentifyMyParts.x will all print out 2, since they all refer to the same thing. The comment `//Prints 1` is a comment suggesting what it will print, which of course it will not -- ignore that, trust the code ;)

Comment: Oh.. I get it now that makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

`a.x` and `b.x` are the exactly same variable, called by different names. When you print them out one after another, they *have* to* have the same value (the one assigned last), so both prints will be `2`.

BTW, I really dislike the design decision that allowed `MyClass.staticVar` be also accessible as `myClassInstance.staticVar`. Oh well.

---

*) Not quite true; they could give different values if a concurrent thread modifies it in between. Ignore this if you don't know about threads yet.